How to perform single synchronous and multiple asynchronous requests in Python?
I'm working on a Python script where I need to make an initial request to obtain an ID. Once I have the ID, I need to make several additional requests to get data related to that ID. I understand that these subsequent requests can be made asynchronously to improve performance. However, I'm not sure how to implement this effectively.
Here's a simplified version of my current synchronous approach:
import requests

# Initial request to get the ID
response = requests.get('https://api.example.com/get_id')
id = response.json()['id']

# Subsequent requests to get data related to the ID
data1 = requests.get(f'https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info1').json()
data2 = requests.get(f'https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info2').json()
data3 = requests.get(f'https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info3').json()

# Processing the data
process_data(data1, data2, data3)

I would like to make the requests to info1, info2, and info3 asynchronously. How can I achieve this using asyncio or any other library?
I've looked into httpx, but I'm not sure how to structure the code correctly. Any help or example code would be greatly appreciated!

Similar but using a task group (python >= 3.11)
import httpx
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get('https://api.example.com/get_id')  
        id = response.json()['id']
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            task1 = tg.create_task(client.get(f'https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info1'))
            task2 = tg.create_task(client.get(f'https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info2'))
            task3 = tg.create_task(client.get(f'https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info3'))
    # Processing the data
    process_data(task1.result(), task2.result(), task3.result())
        



There is nothing preventing one from using async systems synchronously, one simply has to await any actions they want to finish prior to the next scheduled matter.
The main difficulty is in making an application async compatible, which can be significantly more challenging.
I have implemented the surrounding structure for the task you described below. Wider considerations for the surrounding code & structure would likely be wise, if you wish to implement this in a long-term project.
import httpx
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        # Initial request to get the ID
        response = await client.get('https://api.example.com/get_id')  
        id = response.json()['id']
        print('done with sync task')
        
        # Subsequent requests to get data related to the ID
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(client.get(f'https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info1'))
        task2 = asyncio.create_task(client.get(f'https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info2'))
        task3 = asyncio.create_task(client.get(f'https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info3'))
        
        # Only await the tasks after having scheduled them all. With larger task counts asyncio.gather() should be considered.
        data1 = (await task1).json()
        data2 = (await task2).json()
        data3 = (await task3).json()
        print(data1, data2, data3)

asyncio.run(main())

Note how the initial API call is fully synchronous, and could also be performed using response = httpx.get('https://api.example.com/get_id') without requiring any await. Given we're already inside a httpx Client, that would be a bit of an anti-pattern though.
I would strongly recommend you to read through the httpx documentation, they were an excellent entry point when I was first introduced to asynchronous programming. asyncio docs for reference

ThreadPool is probably the easiest way to do them in parallel:
(because the requests library is a good citizen and releases the GIL while waiting for the HTTP response, these do run in parallel)
import requests

# Initial request to get the ID
response = requests.get("https://api.example.com/get_id")
id = response.json()["id"]

# Subsequent requests to get data related to the ID
# do these requests in parallel:

# Option 1: Using threads
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def get_data(url: str):
    return requests.get(url).json()


urls = [
    f"https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info1",
    f"https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info2",
    f"https://api.example.com/data/{id}/info3",
]

with ThreadPool(3) as pool:
    data1, data2, data3 = pool.map(get_data, urls)


def process_data(*args):
    pass


# Processing the data
process_data(data1, data2, data3)



I'm not sure if OP asked for doing these in parallel. From my understanding of the question, they just want to use async operation for the requests. OP needs to make sure, if this is being used in any production app, there should be a consideration before doing this, because this is using three threads at the same time instead of one. Basically, if this is an endpoint, then three times resource is needed to finish one api call.

3 threads don't use 3 times the system resources. Threads are lightweight and python has the GIL so you are never going to be doing 3 times the work at once in python land. The only exception to that is when you are calling some code that is not in python land and does release the GIL - i.e. some library that is a python wrapper to some lower level code - i.e. a python extension written in C/Rust etc. In this particular example, the 3 things can run in parallel because most of the time is spent waiting for the HTTP response which releases the GIL. Waiting doesn't use 3 times the resources.

In my experience in writing production code - threads are much easier to write (and to maintain and reason about) than async and perform just as well. As soon as you write one async function in python (and in many other languages like JavaScript and Rust) you end up needing to make a bunch of other functions that call said functions also async and the async propagates all over your app. This may be acceptable or you may use asyncio.run but in my experience threads are just simpler and easier and provide very comparable performance. The OP said "improve performance" - so that is what I did

As with almost every problem - there are multiple ways to achieve similar results and I just offered one of them. People can pick and choose if they want to go down the async or the threads route, depending on their requirements and constraints.

Thanks @Alex L for the info. I didn’t know I could use Threadpool to create multiple threads instead of creating multiple processes

The links in your code don't work,
I used a different API.
See if this solution will help you.
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def fetch_data(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.json()

async def main():
    base_url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # Synchronous request for basic information
        response = await session.get(base_url + 'people/')
        people = (await response.json()).get("results", [])

        # Asynchronous requests to personal pages
        tasks = [fetch_data(session, person["url"]) for person in people]
        data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        for person in data:
            print(person["name"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


